# Number of try for $p$ and $q$ to find $m$(Brute-force a RSA key)

Tags: probability, cryptography

To find $m$ there is a method called Brute-force that calculates all possible combination and apply them to find the only one true answer.

This is an example:

Prime number (Bitsize: 512) (*): p
============================================================= dec ==== 
13059313724319126815698328933761111023445599295666419531591666294317326706135802771868772964777544791631665594397048785390359533210057462940524389248589953

Prime number (Bitsize: 512) (*): q
============================================================= dec ==== 
11292070857539789665049405958629835091255215659291199773104193934768436659737674012016529740997052319915770253093741328930874356021224885805564002892313913

Modulus (Bitsize: 1024): n=p*q
============================================================= hex ==== 
d1ffe2398f9c81edb18b3a94a59939e54c751961c27c6e377d55b1c6477a6b88d7404d9f2dcad2928b6058d1f63339cb63ab9e48c0882ca55a044719ab304edd30811ad743aefaeb5d1576685e58808635d8837c7bc097343cddb21f88d72c3b7cc4a6b45a5f0e5214844a1ef88decec9c0780b513772e64d0cadad3161571b9

looking for a mathematical formula to estimate the number of entire test values.

Comment: Perhaps other people on this site are more savvy in the technical field from which you are asking (which appears to be cryptography) are able to understand what it is you are asking for, but I could not tell, even after re-reading your question a couple of times...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking, given a product of two primes $m$, how many ways are there to factor it as $m=pq$ where $p,q$ are primes?

Comment: @R1w By the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), the will be precisely 1 way to factor a number as the product of primes.

Comment: Please make clear what you are asking.  In RSA we choose two large primes, $p,q$ and multiply them to get $m$.  There is then exactly one way to factor $m$.  Are you suspecting there may be more?  Or are you asking about more general $m$ of this size.  An $m$ that has more prime factors will have more factorizations.

Comment: Finally it is clear you want the number of numbers to try for $p$, not the number of factorizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a brute force trial you are simply taking $m$, guessing $p$ and dividing to see if it comes out even.  If you know nothing about how $p$ and $q$ are chosen, you need to try all the primes up to $\sqrt m$, which is about $\frac 12\cdot \frac {\sqrt m}{\log m}$.  Traditionally we force $p$ and $q$ to be just about the same size, so you can reduce this a bit but not much, say $10\%$

If $m$ has $1024$ bits it is about $2^{1024} \approx 1.8\cdot 10^{308}$.  There are about $2^{512} \approx 1.3\cdot 10^{154}$ choices for $p$.  If you had an oracle to tell you which of these are prime, it is about $1$ in $355$ of them, so that would cut the number to try to about $3.8 \cdot 10^{151}$.  You are not going to get this done any time soon.